# Speed up Mathematica code involving Convolve

Tags: functions, coding-style, code-review, convolution

I'm trying to plot the averaged autocorrelation function of a random wire profile $\xi(x)$ which is build from unitsteps which are each L units long. To calculate the average I'm generating nMax realizations of the profile, then I proceed to calculate the autocorrelator $\langle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \xi(x)\xi(x-y)~dx \rangle$. Brackets indicate averaging over the `nMax` copies of the profile. My final goal is to plot this expression as a function of `y`.

I started out by using both the built-in `Mean` and `Convolve` functions, however it is ridiculously slow on my machine (late 2007 MacBook). To give you an idea, it takes 150 seconds to calculate `corr[0]` alone (even with `nMax=1`).

Is there anything I'm completely missing here? Or can someone of you even hint at a faster and more elegant approach to this?

```
L = 1.; (* step length *)
nMax = 1; (* number of realizations for averaging *)
nSteps = 1; (* number of modules in wire *)

(* define module *)
mod[x_] := UnitStep[x - L + 1.5]*UnitStep[L - x - 0.5]
(* define random profile *)  
xi[x_] := 
  Sum[RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}]*mod[x - n L], {n, -nSteps, nSteps}];
(* get nMax realizations of random profile *)
xiTmp[x_] = Table[xi[x], {n, 1, nMax}]
(* define correlator; normalized to corr[0]=1 *)
corr[y_]:=Table[Convolve[xiTmp[x][[n]], xiTmp[x][[n]], x, y]/
 Convolve[xiTmp[x][[n]], xiTmp[x][[n]], x, 0], {n, 1, nMax}]
(* plot mean autocorrelator *)
Plot[Mean[corr[y]],{y,-5,5},PlotRange->All,Filling->Axis]
```

Comment: I'm not following your code but the slowdown seems be because of `0` in `Convolve[xiTmp[x][[n]], xiTmp[x][[n]], x, 0]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE @nilfisque! Why all these `Table` that run from 1 to 1? If there is a slowdown and you want to get to the root of it, simplifying the code to bare minimum for readability and easier debugging is appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate? This Convolve[f,f,x,y]/Convolve[f,f,x,0] construct ensures that corr[y=0] is equal to unity and this is an essential requirement in my analysis.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Thank you. I actually tried to scale down the code but apparently did a very bad job at it. The Table functions stem from my original calculations where I wanted to average over >100 realizations. These calculations didn't finish in a reasonable amount of time, so I set them to 1 for optimization.

Comment: If what you need is the final plot, is it acceptable for you to do it in discrete fashion? So you can avoid symbolic calculation and use `ListConvolve` to speed up.

Comment: btw if you want to calculate autocorrelator of `f[x]`, you may want to use `Convolve[f[x], f[-x], x, y]` instead of `Convolve[f[x], f[x], x, y]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First I want to say, as you mentioned in [your comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8838/speed-up-mathematica-code-involving-convolve#comment25409_8838) that your ultimate goal is to to do it for `nMax` over 100, I suggest you first symbolicly calculate the correlation of the following function, treating $r_n$ ($n=-s,-s+1,\dots,s$, and $s$ is `nSteps` for short) as variables as $x$:

$$\xi(x,r_{-s},r_{-s+1},\dots,r_{s})=\sum _{n=-s}^{s} r_n\, \text{mod}(x-n\,L)\text{.}$$

On the othe hand, if what you need is only the final plot, maybe it's more convenient to do it in discrete style. Supplying each $\xi(x)$ as a discrete `List`, you can use numerical `ListCorrelate` on your data for great speed-up, avoiding symbolic calculation of `Convolve` for functions. Here we calculate the plot for `nMax` = **1000**:

```
L = 1.; (* step length *)
nMax = 1000; (* number of realizations for averaging *)
nSteps = 1; (* number of modules in wire *)

(* define module *)
mod[x_] := UnitStep[x - L + 1.5]*UnitStep[L - x - 0.5]
(* define random profile *)  
xi[x_] := 
  Sum[RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}]*mod[x - n L], {n, -nSteps, nSteps}];
(* get nMax realizations of random profile *)
xiTmp[x_] = Table[xi[x], {n, 1, nMax}]
```

Now we discrete the `xiTmp` on a x-grid:

```
dx = .01;

{xiSupportInf, xiSupportSup} = 
     {(-(nSteps - 1))*L - 3/2, (nSteps + 1)*L - 1/2}; 

yWidth = xiSupportSup - xiSupportInf;

AbsoluteTiming[xiTmpDiscrete = 
       Transpose[Table[xiTmp[x], {x, xiSupportInf, 
             xiSupportSup, dx}]]; ]
```

> {4.2972458, Null}

```
Lx = Dimensions[xiTmpDiscrete][[2]];

AbsoluteTiming[
   corrArray = ((#1/#1[[Lx]] & )[ListCorrelate[#1, 
                #1, {-1, 1}, 0]] & ) /@ xiTmpDiscrete; ]
```

> {0.0950055, Null}

```
ListLinePlot[
 Transpose[
  {Range[-yWidth, yWidth, dx], 
       Mean[corrArray]}
  ], PlotRange -> All, 
   Filling -> Axis]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

This may still be slow for large `nSteps`, in that case you may want to somehow `Compile` the `xiTemp` function.

**Update: some note about the correlate calculation**

Here `xiTmpDiscrete` is a `List` whose elements are those $\xi(x)$s (in discrete form, so each $\xi(x)$ itself is a `List` too, in the form $\{\xi(x_1), \xi(x_2), \dots, \xi(x_{\mathrm{Lx}})\}$).

The pure function `ListCorrelate[#1, #1, {-1, 1}, 0]&` takes a $\xi(x)$ as its input, calculates the discrete version correlate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\xi(x)\xi(x-y)\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Then the result is supplied to function `#1/#1[[Lx]] &`. As the `ListCorrelate` result with above setting is symmetric, the middle element, which is the `Lx`-th one, correspond to auto-correlate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\xi(x)\xi(x-0)\,\mathrm{d}x$, so `#1/#1[[Lx]] &` effectively performs the normalization. Thus now we have obtained the normalized correlator for one $\xi(x)$.

By taking advantage of `/@`, which is a short-form for `Map`, the above process is performed for each $\xi(x)$ in `xiTmpDiscrete`. The final result `corrArray` is a array of size `nMax` $\times$ `Lx`. By applying `Mean` on it, mean is performed among rows, obtain a 1-dimension `List` of length `Lx`, which is a discrete version of your `Mean[normalisedcorr[y]]` on interval $[$ `-yWidth`, `yWidth` $]$.

Comment: Silvia, this is indeed way faster than my initial method, thanks a lot! May I ask you a further question about your construction of `corrArray`? While this line is very compact, I'm not sure I entirely understand it. So at first you apply the list `xiTmpDiscrete` to `ListCorrelate` and than the resulting expression is applied to `#1/#1[[Lx]]`. I've tried to cast this into code I'm more familiar with (at least right now) and came up with `ListCorrelate[xiTmpDiscrete, xiTmpDiscrete, {-1, 1}, 0]/
 ListCorrelate[xiTmpDiscrete, xiTmpDiscrete, {-1, 1}, 0][[Lx]]`, which however results in an error.

Comment: @nilfisque please see my update. (it's too long for a comment.)

Answer (score 8):

Here are two things you can do to speed up this code.

### 1. Do the convolution with symbolic `y`

Because you have defined `corr` using `SetDelayed`, the table of `Convolve` expressions will be re-evaluated every time you evaluate `corr[number]`. The normalisation term with y=0 is causing a particular slow down, though I'm not sure why exactly.

If you instead use `Set` the convolution will be computed straight away with symbolic `y`, which means that every time you evaluate `corr[number]` Mathematica will just take the expression it has already computed and insert `number` in place of `y`.

```
corr[y_] = Table[Convolve[xiTmp[x][[n]], xiTmp[x][[n]], x, y], {n, 1, nMax}];
```

You'll notice that I've removed the normalisation term. Now that we have a symbolic expression for `corr[y]` we can get the normalisation term simply by evaluating `corr[0]`. The normalised correlation can therefore be defined as:

```
normalisedcorr[y_] := corr[y]/corr[0]
```

### 2. Convert `xi` to a `Piecewise` expression

The convolution integrals can be made faster by expressing `xi[x]` as a `Piecewise` expression instead of in terms of `UnitStep`. To do this we can insert `PiecewiseExpand` into the definition of `xi`:

```
xi[x_] := PiecewiseExpand @ Sum[RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}]*mod[x - n L], {n, -nSteps, nSteps}]
```

For convenience, the whole tweaked code is:

```
L=1.;nMax=1;nSteps=1;
mod[x_]:=UnitStep[x-L+1.5]*UnitStep[L-x-0.5];
xi[x_]:=PiecewiseExpand@Sum[RandomReal[{-0.5,0.5}]*mod[x-n L],{n,-nSteps,nSteps}];
xiTmp[x_]=Table[xi[x],{n,1,nMax}];
corr[y_]=Table[Convolve[xiTmp[x][[n]],xiTmp[x][[n]],x,y],{n,1,nMax}];
normalisedcorr[y_]:=corr[y]/corr[0] 
Plot[Mean[normalisedcorr[y]],{y,-5,5},PlotRange->All,Filling->Axis]
```

This takes about 19 seconds on my PC with `nMax=100`

Comment: Does this do the same thing?  You completely removed the troublesome `Convolve[xiTmp[x][[n]], xiTmp[x][[n]], x, 0]`.  Also, since the OP is using `RandomReal` I assumed caching was verboten.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I think so. The troublesome piece simply computes the convolution evaluated at y=0. Since we have already computed the convolution for *all* values of y, it's not really required. We can just normalise with `corr[y]/corr[0]`

Comment: @SimonWoods, thank you for your input on my code, I appreciate it a lot! These suggestions are exactly what I was hoping for (I'm especially excited about the elegant `corr[y]/corr[0]` construction. :)).